# httr requests in R not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on specific internet connection (but works on Windows 10)

Tags: r, network-programming, ubuntu-16.04, httr

No `httr:GET/POST/etc.`  is working on a specific internet connection of mine. The computer has access to the internet, and I can make `curl` requests from the terminal. Using Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

For example: `httr::GET("https://httpbin.org/get")`

The error I get is:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [httpbin.org] Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

I basically know nothing about networking, so simple answers are better if it's a networking issue!

**UPDATE**

It works on Windows 10, just not Ubutnu 18.04. Any ideas?

Comment: GET doesn't exist on the site? Can you visit it on a browser(personally cannot)

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? I am not sure what info you're trying to get from this site. It seems like a site explaining how requests work?

Comment: My fault - just fixed it. No `httr` request is working at all for me on this internet connection in particular.

Comment: That might be a local issue then. Perhaps you're behind a firewall? This works for me: `httr::GET("https://httpbin.org/get",content_tye="application/json")`

Comment: I looked into this and nothing changed. Update: it seems to be working fine on Windows, but just Ubuntu.